# Saving and Loading Content in Javascript

Tags: javascript, load, save, loading, saving-data

Here is my save, load, and what I'm trying to load. I don't fully grasp the save/load mechanic but I've gotten it to work for what I need so far. I ran into a problem keeping something updated and don't know what I need to call/ can call to make it work.

```
    //Saves my game and the elements inside
function saveGame() { 
var save = {
stick: stick,
rock: rock,
wood: wood,
stamina: stamina,
research1Progress: research1Progress
}
localStorage.setItem("save",JSON.stringify(save));
}
//Somehow I save content, Look into this more

    //This is what I call to load my game
window.onload = function loadGame() {
var savegame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("save"));
if (typeof savegame.stick !== "undefined") stick = savegame.stick;
if (typeof savegame.rock !== "undefined") rock = savegame.rock;
if (typeof savegame.wood !== "undefined") wood = savegame.wood;
if (typeof savegame.stamina !== "undefined") stamina = savegame.stamina;
if (typeof savegame.research1Progress !== "undefined") research1Progress = savegame.research1Progress;
document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;
document.getElementById("rock").innerHTML = rock;
document.getElementById("wood").innerHTML = wood;
document.getElementById("stamina").innerHTML = stamina;
document.getElementById("research1Progress").innerHTML = research1Progress;
}

    //Adding research1progress fixed first issue
    //Need to update load to keep crafting2 on screen even after browser is closed

function researchStick() {
    if (stick >= 1 && research1Progress < 100) {            // Want to be able to show progress
        stick = stick - 1;                                      // each time you click me I want to use 1 stick
        research1Progress = research1Progress + 5;              // each stick brings research progress up 5
        document.getElementById("stick").innerHTML = stick;     // Show the player the update
    }
    if (research1Progress == 100) {                         // When reaches 100
        showInlineContent('crafting2');                         // show crafting2
    }
// when research hits 100 unlocks blunt object for crafting
// this clickable button should hide after completion
// add achievement for first research project

}
```

Trying to figure out what I need to place in the load/save section to make it so after players unlock showInlineContent('crafting2'); it continues to be shown on the browser screen after the players initiate a save. right now it saves my content but after I reload the webpage the research is still complete but I have to click the research project one more time to show 'crafting2' again

Any hints as to how I would go about saving other data?

Comment: Perhaps you should *launch* `researchStick()` in your `loadGame` function, no? Showing the code behind `showInlineContent` would also be a tremendous help.

Comment: @Tyblitz I had not replaced my code here yet but I changed a few things and added  showInlineContent('bluntObjectName');
showInlineContent('bluntObjectValue'); to my loadGame. seems to be working for now. Thanks for the help. I'll test other methods out.